# What is this object/module and where can I find it or how can I make it?

Tags: jquery, drupal, web, module

On this site, there are these cubes, titled "Events" "Mixes" and "Gallery." When one hovers over them, the cube has a rotate animation, and also on mouse out.

If you could tell me what the name of the plugin/module they are using, or how I can achieve the same thing that would be great.

[Link to Website with rotating cube buttons](http://djxplosiveboom.com/web/)

I have looked at the source code and they appear to be using drupal, and I think the cubes are jquery powered, but I don't really know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All they're doing is moving the `background-position` up & down.

Here's the relevant piece of code they're using:

```
$(function(){
    $('.sprite')
        .css( {backgroundPosition: "0 0"} )
        .mouseover(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 -176px)"}, {duration:500})
        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, {duration:500})
        })

});
```

Comment: Wow, well then that is a lot simpler than I thought and means I don't have to switch over to Drupal, thanks!

Comment: @Christopher Bonilla - this is jQuery (the language is javascript :P). Since you tagged your question with [tag:jQuery], I assume you're familiar with it?!

Comment: Yeah, i said jquery cause I saw some in the source code, but I found the javascript tag, and I actually know nothing about it, but I did find how it was used, I just needed to find out where they were pulling the image from, which is the css file. Thanks for your help!